# TTS not working in tensorflow for gesture detection android app

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, text-to-speech, gesture-recognition

- I am making a gesture detection app in which if you perform the ASL it detects the sign you are performing and shows the result like below.
  [image]
- I have also implemented a `EditText` field in which the result is retrieved. I am trying to to `Text-To-Speech` or `TTS`.
- I am using `Log.i("Recognitionss", String.valueOf(results.get(0).getTitle()));` to log the result in `DetectorActivity.java`
- Log result is generated like below which gives me the gesture, and I have passed it to the `XML` file

```
2021-04-14 19:34:24.826 29814-29924/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/Recognitionss: L
2021-04-14 19:34:24.835 29814-29924/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: MultiBoxTracker: Processing 1 results from 123
2021-04-14 19:34:24.855 29814-29814/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Preparing image 128 for detection in bg thread.
2021-04-14 19:34:24.876 29814-29924/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Running detection on image 128
```

- I have added `Button` and `EditText` to my `bottom sheet` navigation.

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSpeak"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Voice Conversion" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:inputType="text"/>
```

- Java code for `TTS`

```
package org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection;

import android.os.Build;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Locale;

public class AndroidTextToSpeechActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSpeak;
    EditText editText;

    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tfe_od_layout_bottom_sheet);

        // Init TextToSpeech
        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA ||
                            result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This language is not supported!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else {
                        btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                        textToSpeech.setPitch(0.6f);
                        textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(1.0f);

                        speak();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Init View
        btnSpeak = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                speak();
            }
        });
    }

    private void speak() {
        String text = editText.getText().toString();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
        } else {
            textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (textToSpeech != null) {
            textToSpeech.stop();
            textToSpeech.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

- The problem is when I click on the button there is no voice feedback and there is no error in the console or logcat.

Comment: can you log this   _public void onInit(int status) { _ status value to check what status you are getting

Comment: @kelvin i have updated my question with my solution, so i will be no more implementing anything as of now i have got the output i wanted.

Comment: so just post it as answer and accept your own answer so that it doesn't draw attention.

Comment: okay, thankyou. sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **SOLUTION**
- Added the below code in this in which have added a `textview` and a `imageview` you can use button or whatever you like to use, which gave me the below output.
  [image]
- Then under `CameraActivity.java` define the `ImageView`

```
  private speakImageView;
  speakImageView = findViewById(R.id.speak1);
  // set onClick listener
  speakImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

- Then under onClick method I am defined if the particular letter is encountered play that letter sound. I have used `mp3` sound file as I was not able to implement `TTS` so I opted to go with `mp3`.

```
@Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // some code
    ...
    // voice for the detected alphabet
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.speak1) {
      // this is the value we are showing
      EditText mEdit = findViewById(R.id.editText);
      String letter = mEdit.getText().toString();
      if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
        final MediaPlayer mp100 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.letter_a);
        mp100.start();
      }
      else if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
        final MediaPlayer mp100 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.letter_b);
        mp100.start();
      }
      // similarly you can do the same for other alphabets also
    }
  }
```

- Not the ideal approach but as ```TTS`` didn't worked for me, used this method after almost searching for a week or 2 week as I am new to android.